# Grid layout: How do I make the renderer ignore intermediate tags?

Tags: html, angular, css, grid-layout

I'm organising some <div>s in a grid layout, like this:

CSS

```
.grid {
  width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
  <div>First cell</div>
  <div>Second cell</div>
  <div>Third cell</div>
  <div>Fourth cell</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m47ody94/5/

So far, so good. However, I'm using Angular, and I want to contain each pair of cells within a component. The DOM ends up looking more like this:

```
<div class="grid">
  <component>
    <div>First cell</div>
    <div>Second cell</div>
  </component>
  <component>
    <div>Third cell</div>
    <div>Fourth cell</div>
  </component>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m47ody94/6/

The arrangement of cells on screen has changed, because the inner <div>s are no longer aware that they're part of a grid; instead, the first <component> takes up one cell and its two constituent <div>s are rendered as normal block elements within that cell, and likewise the second.

Normally (and correct me if I'm wrong), non-standard tags like <component> hold no significance to the browser's renderer, unless they're given some via CSS. Why here? Can I keep them in, as they're important to my Angular app, but tell the renderer to ignore them and treat each <div> as one cell of the grid, like in my first example?

Comment: Indeed, to correct you: "non-standard tags like <component> hold no significance to the browser's renderer, unless they're given some via CSS" is wrong. Manifestly, in fact, given they are treated as grid elements, because they're just child nodes of the element which is a `display: grid`.

Comment: Your project will be much more easy if you get rid of the *component*

Answer (score 4):

As of 2020 and top evergreen browsers, one of solutions is to use `display: contents` for `<component>`, so the tag is ignored and its contents are rendered as if they were assigned to its parent element directly. It is just important not to forget that this tag still needs to be considered when using CSS selectors or DOM operations, so that for example to style `div` selectors use of `.grid > component > div` is needed.